# How to limit number of DoFn threads for streming job, apache beam, dataflow backend, python

Tags: streaming, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a problem with large number of parallel workers in apache beam with streaming job (dataflow backend, python SDK)

`Initializing SDKHarness with unbounded number of workers.`

Seems that beam produces several hundreds of DoFn instances in several seconds from the beginning from single VM/worker

And I cant find place in sourcecode, where i can limit this "unbounded" number.

I need to limit them, because in `process()` and in `setup()` i have external calls, and i need to decrease outgoing RPS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the runner v2, enabled via:

```
--experiments=use_runner_v2
```

You can make use of the following parameter for defining the number of threads per process :

```
--number_of_worker_harness_threads
```

Comment: I would say, that this variable is using for number of workers now, not for hundreds of threads in streaming.    ########

if self.debug_options.number_of_worker_harness_threads:
       pool.numThreadsPerWorker =( self.debug_options.number_of_worker_harness_threads)



numThreadsPerWorker: 

The number of threads per worker harness. If empty or unspecified, the service will choose a number of threads (according to the number of cores on the selected machine type for batch, or 1 by convention for streaming)